# Can't create multiple sqlite tables

Tags: python, sqlite

I've been trying to create a database which contains two tables but for some reason I keep getting this error I've looked at other peoples code and from what I can see its the exact same... I also try to run it one at a time but it only makes one table not both... I may just be missing something small?

## Code

```
import sqlite3

connie = sqlite3.connect('pb.db')

c = connie.cursor()

c.execute("""
CREATE TABLE users(
_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
username TEXT,
password TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE results(
_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
users_id INTEGER,
simresult INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(users_ID) REFERENCES users(_ID)
);
""")

connie.commit()
```

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/britsge/OneDrive - Iona College/Year 11/DSO/PowerballSite/db-create-user.py", line 19, in <module>
    """)
sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.
```

Comment: Try using `executescript` instead of `execute`. It can execute multiple SQL statements with one call.

Comment: Side note: there is no need to `commit` a `create table` statement. It is a DDL operation, that takes effect immediately.

Comment: @maciek97x thanks that works but for some reason it only creates the results table not the users table...

Answer (score 0):

```
c.execute("""
CREATE TABLE users(
_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
username TEXT,
password TEXT
);
""")

c.execute("""
CREATE TABLE results(
_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
users_id INTEGER,
simresult INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(users_ID) REFERENCES users(_ID)
);
""")

connie.commit()
```

Comment: That worked but its only showing the results table but not the users table, would that be a pycharm visual glitch or did the table not actually create?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I created some time ago for a project of mine. You pass in the table name as a string you want to create (calling create_table('table_name')) from your main driving logic and do it this way:

```
def create_table(ptbl):

    """ Assemble DDL (Data Definition Language) Table Create statement and build
        sqlite3 db table

    Args:
        string: new db table name.

    Returns:
        Status string, '' or 'SUCCESS'.
    """
    retval = ''
    sqlCmd = ''
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
        c = conn.cursor()

        elif ptbl == 'TBL_VDMS_TEMPLATES_MATRIX':

            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (ID INTEGER, FILESET TEXT, VDMS TEXT)'

        elif ptbl == 'TBL_PLACEHOLDER_MAPPING':

            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (PLACEHOLDER TEXT, MASTER_FIELD TEXT)'

        elif ptbl == 'TBL_VDMS_PLACEHOLDER_MAPPING':

            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (PLACEHOLDER TEXT, VDMS_FIELD TEXT)'

        elif ptbl == 'TBL_DESIGNATIONS':

            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (GRID TEXT, DESIGNATION TEXT)'

        elif ptbl == 'TBL_FILE_MARKER_LINENUMS':
            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (FILENAME TEXT, LINENO INTEGER, PREFIX_DELIM TEXT, ' \
                                                            'MARKER TEXT, SUFFIX_DELIM TEXT)'

        elif (ptbl == 'TBL_TEMPLATE_DMS') or (ptbl == 'TBL_TEMPLATE_FEEDER_DMS') or (ptbl ==
                                                                                             'TBL_TEMPLATE_VAULT_DMS'):

            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (LINENO INTEGER, LINEVAL TEXT)'

        elif ptbl == 'TBL_CABLES':
            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (ID INTEGER, CABLE_NAME TEXT, CABLE_CONTENT TEXT)'

        elif contains(ptbl, '_1_cable'):

            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + '(ID INTEGER, S1 TEXT, A1 TEXT, C1 TEXT)'

        elif contains(ptbl, '_N_cable'):

            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + '(ID INTEGER, SN TEXT, AN TEXT, CN TEXT)'

        else:
            pass

        if sqlCmd != '':
            c.execute(sqlCmd)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

        retval = 'SUCCESS'

    except Error as e:

        retval = 'FAIL'
        print(e)

    return retval
```